About the log canonical polytope
BCHM gives a proof to the following statement:

where $\mathcal{L}(V):=\{\Delta\in V\ |\ (X,\Delta)\text{ is lc}\}$.
Could someone explain to me how to comprehend the underlined sentence? And why are these affine linear functions "rational"? Thanks.
